# Implementing URL rewriting in PHP using framework

Tags: php, url-rewriting

**This is more for information then a problem.**(On searching **Stack Overflow** I found more problem related questions then solution or explanation)
 I am working on a PHP website for real estate,something very similar to [this](http://www.proptiger.com/property-in-pune-real-estate.php).Here,each property in the list takes the user to a different page(**URL shows a different link for each property clicked**) and displays the details.Also the  **and**  tags are changed.There are about 600 properties in a single city on the website and definitely there cannot be **600 Pages**.Hence they must have used **some framework or URL rewriting** technique to achieve this. I am fairly new to PHP and no experience with frameworks(**having worked on classical PHP**).
 I would like responses/suggestions to understand how such functionality(**Ideally similar to the site**) can be achieved using any **PHP framework or some URL** rewriting technique.
Sorry if the question sounds too broad to explain,but any pointers will also do which can briefly explain the scenario for me to get started.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a module in Apache called [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and by placing a file named `.htaccess` in your web directory with the following content (for example)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

As you can see, when the URL `example.com/some-cool-apartment.php` is requested it is as if the following was requested `example.com/view.php?id=some-cool-apartment`

Of course other web servers (such as IIS) support URL rewriting using other syntax. IIS uses a file named `web.config` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]*)\.php$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/view.php?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I hope that answered your question

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.So in case of the html tag changes,they also are populated dynamically from, say database??

Comment: yes indeed, links and specifically what's inside the `href` property is fetched from a database.

Comment: btw, it would be nice to upvote/accept answers that were helpful to you (not just this one, on your other questions) as some people put time to make the answers easy to understand. If you have a reputation of being greedy and ungrateful you'll have a hard time getting your questions answered.

Comment: I always do that,but some of my questions have gone unanswered and I have it for yours(Late bcoz was leaving my office,so upvoting from home ;))!!I have always accepted answers those useful!!And thanks for your help!! :)